# Securely partitioning Linux

Tags: linux

I came across the following filesystem hierarchy standard however am unsure how I should partition the directories if I am using the logical volume manager and if I wish to secure or harden the installation as much as possible.

[image]

I am aware it depends on what I plan to use the PC/server for however would like to know what is generally recommended as a base installation e.g. keep /var, /var/log, /var/spool because they change constantly.

Secondly how much space is required for the /boot and /root directory assuming if I were to segment directories such as /home, /usr,/var, etcetera as their own mount points?

If I only have the /boot mount point outside the logical volumes, does it provide me with sufficient security? What does it not provide me security against?

Comment: I honestly do not see how partition schemes impact security in any way.

Comment: @grawity - My understanding is that partition schemes allow for granular control.

Comment: For disk space allocation, perhaps. But certainly not more security than simple Unix permissions could provide.

Comment: @grawity - I am not a security expert but from my basic readings, it seems to have to do with reducing the attack surface.

Comment: Studying security, I can't see how a multi-partition scheme would improve security. If an attacker has any interface to your partition scheme then they already have too much access. Access controls are your application/operating system/filesystem's jobs, not your partition table. The attack surface won't change substantially depending on partition scheme, they'll still be mounted to the same places.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve here. Maybe restate what you're trying to do differently? The closest thing I can come up with to your question are encrypting file systems, but I don't think that's what you're getting at.

Comment: @jcrawfordor - The simplest example I can think for Denial of Service attacks. Although an attacker may not have direct access to the partition scheme, they can certainly take advantage of it. I can appreciate that access controls are the operating systems' job but it seems all the articles I have read to date tend to advise to partition in some form or shape hence my query that there must be then a base partition scheme that provides basic security against particular attacks.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding your basic readings. Partitioning schemes don't affect your security against an attack ("hack"), however you may have read about "securing" your system against rogue processes filling up your hard drive and bringing the system down. For example, if /home is on a separate partition, a user trying to dump in their entire 700TB movie collection would fill up /home, but being on a separate partition it wouldn't hurt the processes that rely on writing to e.g. /tmp to function. So you're "secure" against certain disk space issues with complex partitioning schemes.

Comment: Kromey is correct, partitioning can be a useful tool to control your disk usage, along with OS-enforced quotas. I don't see how denial of service attacks apply, though... even if we get really imaginative and pretend that someone is conducting a DoS attack against your hard disk (and if they are, the box has long ago been pwned), the bottleneck is in the disk controller, and it will fail under the same load regardless of the number of partitions under it. Partitions don't give you more devices, they just split up the device in its logical presentation.

Comment: @Kromey  - Thanks and I could most likely be misunderstanding my readings especially with articles such as https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=131035&seqNum=3&rll=1. I would like to understand what they mean if not security.

Comment: @jcrawfordor - Please see my comment to Kromey

Comment: @jcrawfordor One type of DoS attack that could be carried out is what I described -- just filling up the disk with stuff. This will bring many processes to a screeching halt when they can no longer write to the disk, which will cascade into big problems. Try it out for yourself -- depending on the size of the disk it can take a long time, but we're not looking at bottlenecking as the DoS vector anyway.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey That article raises some good points, but if you're relying on your partitioning scheme to secure your system, you've already lost. I suggest you look instead at learning about iptables/iproute, and about Linux file permissions, as both of those will carry you *a lot* further in learning about securing a Linux system, and about Linux itself, than spending so much effort on partitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me provide some contrast to the comments on the question.

If you examine the graphic in some detail, there are some security options that become open with proper partitioning. Some quick examples:

- Anything that is marked static or read-only can be mounted ro (read-only).
- Anything that isn't /dev can be mounted nodev (no device files will be honored).
- Any partition that doesn't require setuid binaries can be mounted nosuid (the setuid bit and setgid bits are ignored).
- Temporary partitions can be mounted or handled in such a way that data on them cannot persist beyond a reboot (e.g. creating a new encrypted file system at each boot with a random key thrown away after mount)
- For some partitions, you could mount them remotely and read-only from an NFS server.  This is a trick that was popular on Solaris.

You can probably come up with some more sophisticated combinations or approaches with some work by examining the options to mount.  Another one that looks useful is noexec, for example.

These changes won't mean perfect security.  They can make various attacks significantly more challenging to implement.  As an example it is harder to drop a trojaned setuid binary on a partition that is mounted nosuid and ro.

In short, partitioning *can* provide some security benefits.  It won't be perfect security, but it can make an attacker's job more difficult.

Comment: Thanks. I am relatively new to the world of Linux so am unaware of setuid and setgid bits but hope to cover them in my Linux journeys. I do however have a few questions in relation to your comments. Apart from the `boot` mount point, what other mount points can be mounted read-only? I take it that every other mount point except `/dev` should be mounted `nodev`? How do you create a temporary partition that prevents data from persisting? I have no idea as yet what noexec does either but will most certainly explore it.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey While this answer is correct, you are getting such a marginal return on your efforts that you would be much better off focusing your learning efforts elsewhere -- such as iptables and Linux file permissions. Once you have a solid understanding of how these work and how Linux operates in general, then you can return to partitions as a means of beefing up your system security.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: Kromey is correct too.  This answer is not useful for the new user.  My answer increases security slightly at a drastic cost to usability (for most).  It is useful for the paranoid sysadmin who wants that little extra security polish and is willing to pay the price for it.  If you don't already know the implications of the changes described then making them will also make your life hell.  Instead, I recommend learning all you can about setuid and setgid; that will take you very useful places.  Your other questions might make good SU questions in their own right.